# Static Buildpack throws CORS 405 Method not allowed for JSON file

Tags: angularjs, cors, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I am using Swisscom Application Cloud (based on Cloudfoundry). I deployed an app usign Static Buildpack and the idea is that this app delivery a JSON file. As soon as I try to access the remote JSON file from a AngularJS application with a GET call, I get a 405 Method Not Allowed on the OPTIONS call. I think it is a CORS issue. Is there anyone out there having an idea how I can make sure that CORS is handled properly by my Static Buildpack app? Is there anyway I can define this in my manifest.yml?

Greets,
Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having tried it myself, I guess you can achieve this by providing a custom nginx configuration (http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/#custom_nginx_configuration) containing CORS settings.

Nginx CORS examples: https://serverfault.com/questions/162429/how-do-i-add-access-control-allow-origin-in-nginx/

Comment: thanks a lot for your help Matthias. It worked by providing an own nginx.conf within the deployed app.